# Flutter google_mobile_ads working in Android emulator but not in release app

Tags: android, flutter, admob

I have an issue with google_mobile_ads. https://pub.dev/packages/google_mobile_ads

They are working in the Android emulator, iOS emulator and iOS release app but not in the release app.

I will show my code ... even though I read that if the ads show up in an emulator they should work in the release app as well.

`home.dart`

```
 static List<String> adKeywords = [
    "keyword1",
    "keyword2",

  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    MobileAds.instance.initialize().then((InitializationStatus status) {
      print('Initialization done: ${status.adapterStatuses}');
      MobileAds.instance
          .updateRequestConfiguration(RequestConfiguration(
              tagForChildDirectedTreatment:
                  TagForChildDirectedTreatment.unspecified))
          .then((void value) {
        createInterstitialAd();
      });
    });
  }

  void createInterstitialAd() {
    _interstitialAd ??= InterstitialAd(
      adUnitId: InterstitialAd.testAdUnitId,
      // adUnitId: AdHelper.bannerAdUnitId, //this uses ad_helper.dart. code below
      request: AdRequest(
        // testDevices: <String>["kGADSimulatorID"],
        keywords: adKeywords,
        // contentUrl: 'http://example.com/bar.html',
        nonPersonalizedAds: true,
      ),
      listener: AdListener(
        onAdLoaded: (Ad ad) {
          print('${ad.runtimeType} loaded.');
          _interstitialReady = true;
        },
        onAdFailedToLoad: (Ad ad, LoadAdError error) {
          print('${ad.runtimeType} failed to load: $error.');
          ad.dispose();
          _interstitialAd = null;
          createInterstitialAd();
        },
        onAdOpened: (Ad ad) => print('${ad.runtimeType} onAdOpened.'),
        onAdClosed: (Ad ad) {
          Helpers().showToast("Refer 5 users to turn ads off.");
          print('${ad.runtimeType} closed.');
          ad.dispose();
          createInterstitialAd();
        },
        onApplicationExit: (Ad ad) =>
            print('${ad.runtimeType} onApplicationExit.'),
      ),
    )..load();
  }
```

ad_helper.dart

```
import 'dart:io';

class AdHelper {
  static String get bannerAdUnitId {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      return "ca-app-pub-...";
    } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
      return "ca-app-pub-...";
    } else {
      throw new UnsupportedError("Unsupported platform");
    }
  }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml - Addes the AppID from the Android App settings

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID" android:value="ca-app-pub-..."/>
```

I'm also seeing these errors in the terminal:

```
E/chromium( 5694): [ERROR:cookie_manager.cc(137)] Strict Secure Cookie policy does not allow setting a secure cookie for http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/ for apps targeting >= R. Please either use the 'https:' scheme for this URL or omit the 'Secure' directive in the cookie value.

W/WebView ( 5694): java.lang.Throwable: A WebView method was called on thread 'FinalizerDaemon'. All WebView methods must be called on the same thread. (Expected Looper Looper (main, tid 2) {36e7d88} called on null, FYI main Looper is Looper (main, tid 2) {36e7d88})
W/WebView ( 5694):      at android.webkit.WebView.checkThread(WebView.java:2592)
W/WebView ( 5694):      at android.webkit.WebView.loadUrl(WebView.java:732)
W/WebView ( 5694):      at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzber.zzfl(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.7.0:133)
W/WebView ( 5694):      at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzber.destroy(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.7.0:495)
W/WebView ( 5694):      at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbeq.destroy(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.7.0:109)
W/WebView ( 5694):      at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbyy.finalize(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.7.0:43)
W/WebView ( 5694):      at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:291)
W/WebView ( 5694):      at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:278)
W/WebView ( 5694):      at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:139)
W/WebView ( 5694):      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
D/StrictMode( 5694): StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.WebViewMethodCalledOnWrongThreadViolation
D/StrictMode( 5694):    at android.webkit.WebView.checkThread(WebView.java:2592)
D/StrictMode( 5694):    at android.webkit.WebView.loadUrl(WebView.java:732)
D/StrictMode( 5694):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzber.zzfl(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.7.0:133)
D/StrictMode( 5694):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzber.destroy(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.7.0:495)
D/StrictMode( 5694):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbeq.destroy(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.7.0:109)
D/StrictMode( 5694):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbyy.finalize(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.7.0:43)
D/StrictMode( 5694):    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:291)
D/StrictMode( 5694):    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:278)
D/StrictMode( 5694):    at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:139)
D/StrictMode( 5694):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
W/Ads     ( 5694): Could not call loadUrl.
```

Answer (score 1):

It is absolutely fine.
The ads will automatically start showing up when you will reach 10-20 active users.

Comment: Ah ... Really? Why isn't that information available in the plugin documentation? :) Thank you.